# How to draw circle, square, and triangle marks in TikZ picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The below is part of my TikZ picture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(10,0);
\filldraw (0,0) circle (3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to place a "square mark" to denote the point at `(10,0)`. How can I place a square mark? Is there anything like

```
\filldraw (10,0) square (3pt);
```

In addition, how may I place a "triangle mark"?

Comment: Perhaps the 'plot coordinates' path instruction, combined with 'mark=...' is something for you. There is a huge plot mark library which includes, among others, square and triangle markers.

Comment: You can add a square with `\filldraw (10,0) rectangle ++(3pt,3pt);`.  Adding `[yshift=-1.5pt]` will center it vertically as the circle is.

Comment: **Related**: [How to draw points in TikZ? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217797/how-to-draw-points-in-tikz)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Three solutions: the first one, using the basic shapes `circle` and `rectangle`, and the `regular polygon` shape from the `shapes` library (as in **Peter Grill**'s comment). The second and third ones use the `plotmarks` library; in the second one, the line and the marks are drawn independently (the marks are placed using `\node`s with `\pgfuseplotmark`); in the third solution, the `plot coordinates` syntax is used, together with the `mark=<mark>` option (as in **Christian Feuersänger**'s comment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(10,0);
\filldraw (0,0) circle (3pt);
\filldraw ([xshift=-2pt,yshift=-2pt]10,0) rectangle ++(4pt,4pt);
\node[fill=black,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,inner sep=1.5pt] at (5cm,0) {};

\draw (0,-1)--(10,-1);
\node at (0,-1) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};
\node at (5cm,-1) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};
\node at (10cm,-1) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};

\draw[mark=*] plot coordinates {(0,-2)} -- plot[mark=triangle*] coordinates {(5cm,-2)} --
  plot[mark=square*] coordinates {(10cm,-2)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The following code shows how to change the size and color of the marks for the second and third solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,-1)--(10,-1);
\node[mark size=3pt,color=red] at (0,-1) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};
\node[mark size=5pt,color=blue] at (5cm,-1) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};
\node[mark size=4pt,color=olive] at (10cm,-1) {\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};

\draw[mark=*,mark size=3pt,mark options={color=olive}] plot coordinates {(0,-2)} 
  -- plot[mark=triangle*,mark options={color=blue}] coordinates {(5cm,-2)} 
  -- plot[mark=square*,mark size=4pt,mark options={color=red}] coordinates {(10cm,-2)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina, it seems to me that your second solution, which uses \pgfuseplotmark, draws the marks a bit off. Is there a way to fix that? I am really interested in a way to use \pgfuseplotmark on the correct position.

Note: I see that only \pgfuseplotmark has this problem, if you put a text in the node it gets centered correctly.

Comment: I can't comment so I comment here: @Gonzalos Medina's answer; when I do as you suggest it seems the markings (squares,circles, etc.) are off by 0.05 in the x-direction. Very strange.

Comment: @Nicola This is now discussed at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144810/15925

Comment: The `\pgfuseplotmark` command should not be used as text! "_Most, but not all, commands of the pgf package must be given within a {pgfpicture} environment._" (pgf manual, v3.0, p.973)

Comment: Isn't the `circle (10px)` syntax deprecated in favor of `circle [radius=10px]`?