# Markers of \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks} in nodes shifted compared to \addplot

Tags: pgfplots

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[mark=*] coordinates
  {(0,0)};
  \node[blue] at (0,0) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[mark=pentagon*] coordinates
{(0,0)};
\node[red] at (0,0) {\pgfuseplotmark{pentagon*}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see in the first picture both markers are at the same position, but not in the second. What do I have to do to get the same positioning of the marker in the node as the one which is plotted with `\addplot`?

**Update**:
Version numbers from log file:

```
Package: pgfplots 2015/05/02 v1.12.1 Data Visualization (1.12.1)
Package: pgf 2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
File: pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2013/07/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.13)
```

Other questions (this is more or less a duplicate):

- [Why does \pgfuseplotmark put so much space to the left of the mark?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235219/why-does-pgfuseplotmark-put-so-much-space-to-the-left-of-the-mark) (see most importantly this one!)
- [Plotmarks of TikZ are off by 0.05 in x-direction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144810/plotmarks-of-tikz-are-off-by-0-05-in-x-direction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is due to the fact that plot marks in PGF are prepared for use inside of drawing instructions. They are not prepared for use in text-mode.

If you want to use drawing instructions in text mode, you have to surround them by a picture, for example as follows

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[mark=pentagon*] coordinates
{(0,0)};
\node[red] at (0,0) {\tikz \pgfextra{\pgfuseplotmark{pentagon*}};};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Does the inline \tikz environment add overhead which should be avoided? Compilation time starts to get a bit slow.

Comment: I suppose it does, yes. Do you really need nodes? You could use shifts to position your markers, followed by `\pgfuseplotmark`. That would have considerably less overhead.

Comment: No, I don't need a node. Is `\shift` a command? Sorry, I am not familiar with the syntax of pgf.

Comment: Ah, ok! I thought you where about to apply an expert operation. These commands like `\pgfuseplotmark` are quite advanced stuff and require familiarity with the PGF basic layer (i.e. the complicated part of PGF). Given that you try to achieve something, I recommend that you ask a question "how to I achieve XYZ using pgfplots/tikz" and listen for advice. That said, you should familiarize yourself with TikZ as such, i.e. chapter III of the pgfmanual. It is simpler. Perhaps TikZ's plot styles are what you need? Aside from that, the `pgfplots` manual might also address your use-cases.

Comment: I have found another way of resolving it: `\node[red] at (0,0) {\nullfont\pgfuseplotmark{pentagon*}};`. This is mentioned in following answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235222/8917.

Comment: do you think the mentioned missing `%` in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235222/8917 will be added into mainline of the plotmarks library, so this question becomes redundant?

Comment: I have already added the missing `%` chars to all affected plot marks. Nevertheless, the solution which adds the markers directly into the text is actually unsupported... I do not know if there are any caveats with it, but it is certainly luck that it works. Normally, you need a picture to draw stuff.