# Why does \pgfuseplotmark put so much space to the left of the mark?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the suggestions from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64573/5626), I decided to use `\pgfuseplotmark` to make marks in my diagram.  However, there is some strange white space inserted to the left of the pgfmarks.  What should I do to remove it?  Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw] at (0,0) {!};
  \node[draw] at (2,0) {\pgfuseplotmark{diamond*}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because of the missing `%` at the end of the plotmark drawing commands in the library. Usually, `\pgfuseplotmark` is used as a standalone command and not put in the text boxes so the inherent TikZ feature of eating up regular font via `\nullfont` takes care of it. But it becomes apparent once you put them in text aware places such as the box of a node.

Quick way to fix is

```
\node[draw] at (2,0) {\nullfont\pgfuseplotmark{diamond*}};
```

or if you are disturbed deeply and want to have it done properly

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{diamond*}
{%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfplotmarksize}}% <-- These % are missing in the originals
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.75\pgfplotmarksize}{0pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-\pgfplotmarksize}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.75\pgfplotmarksize}{0pt}}%
  \pgfpathclose%
  \pgfusepathqfillstroke%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] {\pgfuseplotmark{diamond*}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]