# Nicely embedding tikzpicture in text

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, text

I have the following problem with `tikzpicture`. I've added a plot in my text, which has different line styles and markers inside. For better referencing of single curves, I decided to build the line and marker styles with `tikzpicture`, e.g. a dashed line with a triangle:

```
\newcommand{\dashedTri}{ 
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[black,dashed,line width=1.5pt](0,0) -- (5mm,0); 
                    \node[very thick, mark size=3pt,color=black] at (1mm,0){ 
                        \pgfuseplotmark{triangle} 
                    };
            \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Which creates:

[image]

Note: I also created a diamond marker with a dashed line, by replacing triangle with diamond in the upper code snippet.

Here I have two problems:

1. To have the triangle appear in the middle of the line, I had to put `at (1mm,0)` instead of `(2.5mm,0)`. When using a circle (i.e. `o`), putting `at (2.5mm,0)` was okay for centering. Does anyone know, why I need different positioning for different markers?
2. As indicaded by the (later added) red squares in the text: when using these `tikzpictures` the spacing in the text looks strange, as if the box has a too large width. Adjusting the width (via `resizebox`) hasn't solved the problem. Does anyone know, how to "nicely" embed the tikzpicture in the text?

Cheers,
Robert

Comment: For point 2/ Your issue seems to be due to "hidden" spaces (i.e. end of lines) in your macro definition. You should either wrap it, or make extensive use of `%`

Comment: Your `\dashedTri `command starts with a space: just after the opening brace: So use `{%` there. And there is another one after `\end{tikzpicture}`. Put a `%` also there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that adresses both of your issues:

[image]

Here is how I address your issues:

1. **Vertical alignment:** I defined a common point (named `(base)` at `(0,-.5em)`) in both of your TikZ picture. And I defined it as the reference for the baseline (cf. the global option `baseline=(base)]%` for each `tikzpicture`). It means this particular point will be vertically aligned with your text baseline.
2. **Horizontal blankspace:** In your macro definition, the first line ends with space character (). It means that if you wrap lines 1 and 2, your code will look like this: `\newcommand{\dashedTri}{ \begin{tikzpicture}`; i.e. your embedding a space in your macro definition that is added on top of the space befor your command in your `.tex` document.

---

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

    \newcommand{\dashedTri}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, baseline=(base)]%
        \draw[black,dashed,line width=1.5pt](0,0) -- (5mm,0); 
        \node[very thick, mark size=3pt,color=black] at (2.5mm,0){% 
            \pgfuseplotmark{triangle}%
        };
        \node (base) at (0,-.5ex) {};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

    \newcommand{\dashedDia}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt,baseline=(base)]%
        \draw[black,dashed,line width=1.5pt](0,0) -- (5mm,0); 
        \node[very thick, mark size=3pt,color=black] at (2.5mm,0){% 
            \pgfuseplotmark{diamond}%
        };
        \node (base) at (0,-.5ex) {};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
\begin{document}
    Foo \dashedTri{} bar \dashedDia{} baz.
\end{document}
```

(Note that I changed in your code `\node[very thick, mark size=3pt,color=black] at (1mm,0){` into `\node[very thick, mark size=3pt,color=black] at (2.5mm,0){` (i.e. `1mm` into `2.5mm`) so that the `plotmark` is horizontally aligned regarding the dashed line.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I didn't know, that blank spaces are that crucial :) Cheers

Comment: Regarding issue #1, it's not solved in my code. If I use the marker "o", i get a perfectly centered circle. If I use "triangle" or "diamond", it is horizontally shiften. Do you know of other solutions? Since it works on your code ... 
Cheers

Comment: @Robert check if you have a `%` after the first curly bracket of your `\node` command. You might have another hidden space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I checked my code (basically copy & pasted yours) and added a `%` to each line. The issue persists. However only for the triangle and diamond mark. For centering those I have to use `1mm` and `0.5mm`. Am I missing something else, since the positioning `at (x,y)` needs to be set individually in my case?

Comment: Indeed, point 1 is not addressed. Have a look at [Why does \pgfuseplotmark put so much space to the left of the mark?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235219/64454). But if you run my MWE, you *must* get horizontally centered triangle/diamond (i.e. the same output as in the picture). Is it the case for you? If yes, then the error lies in your real code - and it's difficult to tell where if I don't see it. If not, then try to update your TeX distro.

Comment: I'm running your exact code and do get a different result. I'll try to update my TeX distribution, as you suggested. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @Robert it's weird indeed since `processing(input) -> output`. If we have the same `input`, the only reason for a different `output` is a different `processing`.

Comment: Instead of defining a `(base)` coordinate you can also just use `baseline=-.5ex`.