# include plotmarks in the title of a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to use markers form `\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}`, like: `pentagon*`, `diamond*`, `square*` and `triangle*` in the title of the plot. They work as markers in the plot but i get an error when in want to include them in the title (instead of the "`x`" in `\mathbf{}`)

[image]

This is my code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
b d c
1 a 2   
2 b 4   
3 c 6   
4 d 8   
5 e 10  
6 f 12  
7 g 14  
8 x 16  
9 x 18  
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[paper=a4,ngerman,xcolor=dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolorlist}{
blue!01!green,every mark/.append style={fill=blue!10!black},mark=+\\
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid=both,
        width=12cm, 
        height=9cm,
        xtick pos=left,
        ytick pos=left,
        title style={draw,fill=none,name=legend},
        title={%
            ${\color{red}\mathbf{x}}=\SI{100}{\kilo\Hz}$,
            ${\color{red}\mathbf{x}}=\SI{10}{\kilo\Hz}$,
            ${\color{red}\mathbf{x}}=\SI{1}{\kilo\Hz}$,
            ${\color{red}\mathbf{x}}=\SI{100}{\Hz}$,
            ${\color{red}\mathbf{x}}=\SI{10}{\Hz}$,
            ${\color{red}\mathbf{x}}=\SI{1}{\Hz}$},
        xlabel={R}, ylabel={Z}, 
        legend style={at={(0.02,0.98)},anchor=north west,cells={anchor=west}},
        legend style={font=\footnotesize},
        cycle list name=mycolorlist,
        scatter,
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        scatter/classes={
          x={},% empty argument means: use the default style       
          g={mark=o,red!10!black},
          f={mark=square*,red!20!black},
          e={mark=diamond*,red!30!black},
          d={mark=triangle*,red!40!black},
          c={mark=pentagon*,red!50!black},
          b={mark=*,red!60!black},
          a={mark=oplus,red!70!black},
          z={mark=*,red!80!black}
          },
        ]
        \addplot table [x=b,y=c, meta=d]{data.txt};

        \legend{Z}
   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

`\pgfuseplotmark{square*}` works but it also changes the title.

```
.
.
.
title style={draw,fill=none,name=legend},
        title={%
            ${\color{red}\pgfuseplotmark{o}}=\SI{100}{\kilo\Hz}$,
            ${\color{red}\pgfuseplotmark{square*}}=\SI{10}{\kilo\Hz}$,
            ${\color{red}\pgfuseplotmark{diamond*}}=\SI{1}{\kilo\Hz}$,
            ${\color{red}\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}}=\SI{100}{\Hz}$,
            ${\color{red}\pgfuseplotmark{pentagon*}}=\SI{10}{\Hz}$,
            ${\color{red}\pgfuseplotmark{*}}=\SI{1}{\Hz}$,
            ${\color{red}\pgfuseplotmark{oplus}}=\SI{20}{\mHz}$},
```

It looks like this:

[image]

After using `\def\showmark#1{\tikz[baseline]\node[red]{\pgfuseplotmark{#1}};}` the problem with the y-alignment is fixed, but the title is not centered anymore.

[image]

Using `\showmark{square*}=$\SI{100}{\kilo\Hz}$` instead of `\showmark{x}=$\SI{100}{\kilo\Hz}$` leads to:

[image]

Comment: What error do you get? `\pgfuseplotmark{square*}` (cf. e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64567) works here, though the vertical alignment is off.

Comment: the error is: '! Undefined control sequence.'

Comment: Can you edit the code to show what you tried, and also state the whole error (from the `!` before *Undefined* to the `?` a couple of lines later), so that we can see which macro is undefined.

Comment: Right, so it works, but as I mentioned the vertical alignment (of the plotmarks) is off. As is the spacing before the `=` I see. I don't have a fix at the moment, but I'm sure someone does.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\pgfuseplotmark{name_of_mark}` to show `markers` and you can include it within a node like this

```
\def\showmark#1{\tikz[baseline]\node[red]{\pgfuseplotmark{#1}};}
```

You can modify vertical alignment with `baseline=<yshift>`

**Complete Code**

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
b d c
1 a 2   
2 b 4   
3 c 6   
4 d 8   
5 e 10  
6 f 12  
7 g 14  
8 x 16  
9 x 18  
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[paper=a4,ngerman,xcolor=dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolorlist}{
blue!01!green,every mark/.append style={fill=blue!10!black},mark=+\\
}

\def\showmark#1{\tikz\node[red]{\pgfuseplotmark{#1}};}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid=both,
        width=12cm, 
        height=9cm,
        xtick pos=left,
        ytick pos=left,
        legend style={draw,fill=none,name=legend},
        title={%
            \showmark{x}=$\SI{100}{\kilo\Hz}$,
            \showmark{o}=$\SI{10}{\kilo\Hz}$,
            \showmark{square*}=$\SI{1}{\kilo\Hz}$,
            \showmark{diamond*}=$\SI{100}{\Hz}$,
            \showmark{triangle*}=$\SI{10}{\Hz}$,
            \showmark{pentagon*}=$\SI{1}{\Hz}$},
        xlabel={R}, ylabel={Z}, 
        legend style={at={(0.02,0.98)},anchor=north west,cells={anchor=west}},
        legend style={font=\footnotesize},
        cycle list name=mycolorlist,
        scatter,
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        scatter/classes={
          x={},% empty argument means: use the default style       
          g={mark=o,red!10!black},
          f={mark=square*,red!20!black},
          e={mark=diamond*,red!30!black},
          d={mark=triangle*,red!40!black},
          c={mark=pentagon*,red!50!black},
          b={mark=*,red!60!black},
          a={mark=oplus,red!70!black},
          z={mark=*,red!80!black}
          },
        ]
        \addplot table [x=b,y=c, meta=d]{data.txt};

        \legend{Z}
   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

markers `+` and `x` are defined in `pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex` like this

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{+}
{%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfplotmarksize}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfplotmarksize}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfplotmarksize}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-\pgfplotmarksize}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}
```

---

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{x}
{%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-.70710678\pgfplotmarksize}{-.70710678\pgfplotmarksize}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.70710678\pgfplotmarksize}{.70710678\pgfplotmarksize}}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-.70710678\pgfplotmarksize}{.70710678\pgfplotmarksize}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.70710678\pgfplotmarksize}{-.70710678\pgfplotmarksize}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}
```

You need to add `%` in the end of every line code if you want to fix `+` or `x` marker ( I do not know if this is a bug  in `pgf` or there is  a reason for avoiding `%` ).

**Final Code**

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
b d c
1 a 2   
2 b 4   
3 c 6   
4 d 8   
5 e 10  
6 f 12  
7 g 14  
8 x 16  
9 x 18  
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[paper=a4,ngerman,xcolor=dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolorlist}{
blue!01!green,every mark/.append style={fill=blue!10!black},mark=+\\
}

% Fix x marker
\pgfdeclareplotmark{x}
{%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-.70710678\pgfplotmarksize}{-.70710678\pgfplotmarksize}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.70710678\pgfplotmarksize}{.70710678\pgfplotmarksize}}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-.70710678\pgfplotmarksize}{.70710678\pgfplotmarksize}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.70710678\pgfplotmarksize}{-.70710678\pgfplotmarksize}}%
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}


\def\showmark#1{\tikz[baseline]\node[red]{\pgfuseplotmark{#1}};}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid=both,
        width=12cm, 
        height=9cm,
        xtick pos=left,
        ytick pos=left,
        legend style={draw,fill=none,name=legend},
        title style=draw,
        title={%
            \showmark{x}=$\SI{100}{\kilo\Hz}$,
            \showmark{x}=$\SI{10}{\kilo\Hz}$,
            \showmark{square*}=$\SI{1}{\kilo\Hz}$,
            \showmark{diamond*}=$\SI{100}{\Hz}$,
            \showmark{triangle*}=$\SI{10}{\Hz}$,
            \showmark{pentagon*}=$\SI{1}{\Hz}$},
        xlabel={R}, ylabel={Z}, 
        legend style={at={(0.02,0.98)},anchor=north west,cells={anchor=west}},
        legend style={font=\footnotesize},
        cycle list name=mycolorlist,
        scatter,
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        scatter/classes={
          x={},% empty argument means: use the default style       
          g={mark=o,red!10!black},
          f={mark=square*,red!20!black},
          e={mark=diamond*,red!30!black},
          d={mark=triangle*,red!40!black},
          c={mark=pentagon*,red!50!black},
          b={mark=*,red!60!black},
          a={mark=oplus,red!70!black},
          z={mark=*,red!80!black}
          },
        ]
        \addplot table [x=b,y=c, meta=d]{data.txt};

        \legend{Z}
   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See Björn's update on his question, there is some unwanted whitespace at the start of the title.

Comment: I changed the markers. So, instead of the first ( `\showmark{x}=$\SI{100}{\kilo\Hz}$`) i tried `\showmark{square*}=$\SI{100}{\kilo\Hz}$` and everything is centered again.

Comment: THANKS! works fine!
I have a follow-up question on the legends, which I'll post soon. Would be great if somebody could link it to this one.